# Prevent apps from forcing a certain screen orientation cleanly

Tags: orientation

I currently use an crufty old app from F-droid which overrides the screen orientation using an invisible overlay (I believe) and that works rather well. However, when returning to a forced landscape app from the lockscreen (which is in landscape), android rotates the screen to portrait which I don't want.

I use Spotify and it believes that it knows better than me how I'd like to use my phone and wants to display its playback control screen portrait mode. I obviously need to return to this screen often to change tracks etc.

Is there a better way of doing this? I imagine you'd need something integrated into the SystemUI to get the unlock transition smooth.
I'm not afraid of getting my hands a little dirty with Magisk modules or patches to AOSP components themselves (I build my system from source) but I don't think I'm in a position to be coding something like that myself yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android 12 broke Rotation Manager](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246827/force-an-app-to-be-able-to-auto-rotate-in-android-12) somehow, so I was forced to find a different solution.

By modifying the Android framework with a terrible patch, I was able to make it ignore an activity's screenOrientation preference: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/246838/283347